# $index in ng-repeat not getting replaced angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am using ng-repeat to populate a image list. i need to use $index for naming the images and use it for replacing src of preview div.
$index is not replacing in mouseover section while its getting replaced in name section. what can be the reason and how to correct it.

```
<img onmouseover="preview.src=img{{$index}}.src" name="img{{$index}}" src="{{image.SMALL_PATH}}" alt="" ng-repeat="image in images | filter:query"/>



<div class="preview" align="center">
    <img name="preview" src="images/img1.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: suggest you study some angular tutorials. Don't try mixing native events in angular views. Context is totally different

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) and [`ng-mouseover`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover) Your snippet would be

```
<img data-ng-mouseover="preview.src=image.src" name="image.name" data-ng-src="image.SMALL_PATH" alt="" ng-repeat="image in images | filter:query"/>
```

Comment: my issue is in name="img{{$index}}" is converting to name="img0" but in mouseover section the same is not happening

Comment: You should use `data-ng-mouseover` rather then `mouseover`. It will not work as you're expecting.

Comment: `onmouseover` definitely won't work ... not to mention that `preview` is undefined

Comment: I suppose you mean `preview.src=img{{$index}}.src` for the current iteration, so why don't you use `image` only instead `img{{$index}}`. Both indicates the same

Comment: how about using <img ng-model="content" name="{{image.SMALL_PATH}}" data-ng-src="{{image.SMALL_PATH}}" alt="" ng-repeat="image in images | filter:query"/>. how can i use this ng-model value as src for preview ??

Comment: model's value will be change for each iteration of your loop. You should use 'image.src` instead

Comment: as it was earlier ?? preview.src=img{{$index}}.src. but for this value for preview is not changing.